# let $f$ be a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is there a function that is continuous in this specific manner? $\forall \epsilon >0$ we can choose $\delta = \epsilon$, and it follows that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ whenever $ |x-c| < \delta$?

I immediately though up of $f(x) = x$, but is there any other such function where $\delta = \epsilon \forall \epsilon >0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f(x)=kx$ for $|k| \leq 1$ work.

Answer (score 1):

Any function that satisfy $|f(x)-f(c)| \leq |x-c|$ works.

In particular, function with Lipschitz constant less than equal to 1.